# Using getSignatureStatuses to confirm transaction

Tags: transactions, rpc, signature, jsonrpc-api, confirmationstrategy

I'm using a niche language that doesn't have an existing solana library, thus needing to write my own transaction confirmation logic.

This [github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/23949) issue documents what the new approach for both the ts/rust libraries.

I'm now using `signatureSubscribe`, with `getSignatureStatuses` as a backup, but how do I know when a transaction is valid from `getSignatureStatuses`?
I'm currently retrying `getSignatureStatuses` until either a timeout occurs (when the blockheight is no longer valid), or the `confirmationStatus` is `"finalized"`.

Is it incorrect to always wait for the transaction to be `"finalized"`? Can I wait until it's `"confirmed"` instead, since a confirmed transaction cannot be [rolled-back](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/what-is-the-of-confirmed-transactions-that-get-subsequently-dropped)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait until the transaction 'confirmed'.
The situation that confirmed transaction could be rolled back is if the network operator agree to restart the network.