# What is the % of "processed" transactions that get subsequently dropped?

Tags: commitment

I ran across [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/what-is-the-of-confirmed-transactions-that-get-subsequently-dropped) stating that no confirmed transaction has ever not been finalized, and this got me wondering if there is any stats/a way to measure how frequently processed transactions end up not getting confirmed.